# wmode transparent - entire flash movie disappears using swfobject

Tags: javascript, html, flash, swfobject

I need my flash to appear in front of the background on this website http://work.juanalvarezdj.com/fl/ it loads but its entirely transparent. I need the content to be visible and the background of the flash to be invisible. Here is the flash itself: http://work.juanalvarezdj.com/fl/main.swf. Does anyone see the problem ? How do I leave the content visible but use the website's background ? I'm using swfobject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, wrong z-index style placement.